# Rails: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I am trying to use the gem acts_as_bookable

I get the issue when trying to bundle install

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":


In Gemfile:
    acts_as_bookable was resolved to 0.1.2, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 5)

    rails (~> 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)
```

The gem says it's compatible 3.2.... is there something i can do to overcome this or is the gem dead in the water

Comment: what is you're `activerecord` version?

Comment: if you're using `rails 5.2` it requires `activerecord = 5.2` and `acts_as_bookable` don't support `activerecord > 5`. So it might be the issue.

Comment: Even the latest version of acts_as_bookable (0.1.4) only supports up to version 5 `activerecord < 5.1, >= 3.2`

Comment: @uday yeah i get that, but i asked... is there a way around it :)

Comment: @andreofthecape i get that but i wanted to know if there was a way around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found that the best option with this is to either create a branch, and work through the code to update it yourself.

you could also Start from scratch( in this case not that difficult using) or search for branches that have been created using your version of ruby, rails and active record.